# How to promisify redis module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tried to use `bluebird`

`bluebird.promisify(require('redis'))`

but `redisClient.hmget()` is still not a Promise function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [the docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html). There's an example for redis.

So you can use promisifyAll function and then add the 'Async' postfix for all the functions.

```js
const redis = require('redis');
const bluebird = require('bluebird');

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis);

let client = redis.createClient();

client.hmgetAsync('myhash', 'key').then(data => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})
```